# refresh issue in dynamic AG-GRID Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using ag-grid and the gridoptions is populated dynamically.The problem is in "select all" checkbox selection the gridoption is not getting refreshed.
I have tried this two approach:

```
this.achcGridOptions.api.setRowData(this.achcGridOptions.rowData)
this.achcGridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(this.dynamicolumn(element));
```

But I am getting error as

> "Cannot read property 'api' of undefined"

public dynamiccolumnchc(index: number) {
        this.broaddomain = this.examretun[index]["broadDomainAbbr"];
        return this.getgridcolumns(this.achcGridOptions, this.examretun[index]["broadDomainName"] + " (" + this.examretun[index]["broadDomainAbbr"] + ")", this.examretun[index]["broadDomainAbbr"]);
    }
    public dynamiccolumnsld(index: number) {
        this.broaddomain = this.sldretun[index]["broadDomainAbbr"];
        return this.getgridcolumns(this.asldGridOptions, this.sldretun[index]["broadDomainName"] + " (" + this.sldretun[index]["broadDomainAbbr"] + ")", this.sldretun[index]["broadDomainAbbr"]);
    }
    public dynamiccolumncog(index: number) {
        this.broaddomain = this.cogretun[index]["broadDomainAbbr"];
        return this.getgridcolumns(this.acogGridOptions, this.cogretun[index]["broadDomainName"] + " (" + this.cogretun[index]["broadDomainAbbr"] + ")", this.cogretun[index]["broadDomainAbbr"]);
    }
    public dynamicolumn(headertext: string) {
        return [
            {
                headerName: "dataOrganizerId", field: "dataOrganizerId", suppressFilter: true, hide: true
            },
            {
                headerName: " ", field: "compositeType", width: 100, suppressFilter: true
            },
            {
                headerName: headertext, field: "batteryCompTestName", width: 280, suppressFilter: true//,

```
        },
        {
            headerName: "Score", field: "standardScore", suppressFilter: true, width: 80
        },
        {
            headerName: "", field: "isTransferred", suppressFilter: true, width: 70,
            headerCellRenderer: this.CellHeader,
            cellRenderer: this.transferCellRenderer,
        },
        {
            headerName: "", field: "isDelete", suppressFilter: true, width: 70,
            cellRenderer: this.deleteCellRenderer,
        }
    ];
}
public getgridcolumns(index: GridOptions, titleheader: string, broadDomainID: string) {
    this.selectedxbascores = [];
    this.pswdata.forEach(element => {
        if (element.broadDomain == broadDomainID)
            this.selectedxbascores.push(element);
    });
    if (this.selectedxbascores.length == 0) {
        this.selectedxbascores.push({});
        this.selectedxbascores.push({});
        this.selectedxbascores.push({});
    }
    else if (this.selectedxbascores.length == 1) {
        this.selectedxbascores.push({});
        this.selectedxbascores.push({});
    }
    else if (this.selectedxbascores.length == 2) {
        this.selectedxbascores.push({});
    }
    index = <GridOptions>{};
    index.columnDefs = this.dynamicolumn(titleheader);
    index.rowData = this.selectedxbascores;
    index.rowHeight = 50;
    index.enableCellChangeFlash =true;
    index.enableFilter = true;
    index.headerHeight = 50;
    index.context = {
        batteryService: this,
    }
    index.onGridReady = function (params) {
        params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    }
    return index;
}
selectAll(e) {
    debugger
    var checked = e.target.checked;
    this.checkBoxValue = checked;
    var count = 0;

    if (this.pswdata.length > 0) {
        var testCount = 0;
        this.pswdata = this.pswdata.map(function (a) {
            if (!isNaN(parseInt(a["standardScore"]))) {
                a["isTransferred"] = checked;
                count = count + 1;
                testCount = testCount + 1;
            }
            return a;
        });
        if (testCount > 0)
            this.pswdata.forEach(element => {
                //this.achcGridOptions.api.setRowData(this.achcGridOptions.rowData)
                //this.achcGridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(this.dynamicolumn(element));
            });
            var gridDiv=document.querySelector('#chcGrid');
             alert(gridDiv);
            //gridDiv.tr

    }

    if (count == 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.target.checked = false;
        e.target.parentNode.className = "gridchkbox link";

    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the complete declaration of your achcGridOptions

Comment: @Ahila .B You should put the code into your post. Use the **edit** link under your question.

Comment: I have copied the complete code

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you never assigned your GridOptions to the instance variable `achcGridOptions`. Your components .ts-file should look something like this:

```
gridOptions: GridOptions;

constructor() { this.gridOptions = { ... } }
```

and in the template

```
<ag-grid-angular class="ag-fresh"[gridOptions]="gridOptions"></ag-grid-angular>
```